# Disable form field after value is entered

Tags: wordpress, forms

Can anyone point me in the direction of how I would go about disabling a form field after a value is entered/saved?

I need to do this on a form I have on a WordPress site.

Ideally it would function exactly like WordPress already does on the profile section...preventing you from being able to change your username like below.

[image]

Comment: When you render your form, check if the record for this field is present in database, use [disabled](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/disabled) to add disabled property if it's present. Then, when you save/update your form, check again since disabled property can be removed when you edit age in code inspector.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to check if form submitted if yes then add an disable attribute on the field you need to disable.

```
$("form").submit(function() {  $(".textfield").prop("disabled", true); }
```

OR on server side you can check if the there is any value exist in your array from PHP

```
if(isset($something['say']) && $something['say'] == 'bla') {
/* do something */ }
```